# Proof by Contrapositive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

i am having trouble proving the statement below using Proof by Contrapositive. I have negated the statements as required and then i prove that $n$ is odd if and only if $7n+4$ is odd. However, from there i am stuck and am not sure how to prove the 1st part that if $n$ is negative integer, then $n$ is odd. My work is show below.

```
Original Statement: if n is a positive integer then n is even if and only if is 7n+4 is even.
Contrapositive: If n is negative integer then n is odd if and only if 7n+4 is odd.

Therefore by definition of odd: n = 2k+1
Substitute n:
=7(2k+1)+4
=14k+7+4
=14k+11
=2(7k)+11
Therefore, n is odd and 7n+4 is odd.
```

Thats as far as i got and i dont even know if what i did above is even right though. Thanks.

Comment: That's not the contrapositive.

Comment: then what is? isnt the contrapositive of lets say pVq, not p V not q?

Comment: If you have a statement "If P then Q" and want the contrapositive you get "If $\lnot Q$ then $\lnot P$.

Comment: well, wouldn't "if n is not even" be equivalent to "n is odd"? same goes for "if 7n+4 is not even" would be equivalent to "7n+4 is odd"?.

Comment: @a22asin I would use a direct proof here (as I gave in my answer). You really want to reserve proofs by contradiction, contraposition, etc., for when doing a direct proof is annoying, far more difficult, etc. At least that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no need to prove by contrapositive (unless your teacher is requiring you to do that for some reason). The following direct proof works just fine.

---

**Problem:** Suppose $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ ($n$ being positive is really not necessary). Then $n$ is even if and only $7n+4$ is even.

*Proof.*

**($\to$):** Suppose $n$ is even. Then $n=2\ell$, where $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we have that
$$
7n+4=7(2\ell)+4=14\ell+4=2(7\ell+2)=2m,
$$
where $m=7\ell+2$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, the forward direction is true.

**($\leftarrow$):** Suppose $7n+4$ is even. Consider what happens when $n$ is odd or even.

- $n$ odd: We have $n=2\ell+1$ for some $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$ and so $$
  7(2\ell+1)+4=14\ell+11=2(7\ell+5)+1=2m+1,
  $$ where $m=7\ell+5$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- $n$ even: We have $n=2\ell$ for some $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$ and so
  $$
  7(2\ell)+4=14\ell+4=2(7\ell+2)=2m,
  $$
  where $m=7\ell+2$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

The above analysis shows that $n$ is even if and only if $7n+4$ is even, as desired.

Comment: It should be noted that a proof by contrapositive will be *very* similar. The problem would be stated as follows when proving by contrapositive: $7n+4$ is odd if and only if $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to rephrase the original statement as:

> "Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then $n$ is even if and only if $7n+4$ is even."

With "if and only if" proofs, we would call the forward direction of this proof

> "If $n$ is even then $7n+4$ is even"

This is equivalent to its contrapositive, "If $7n+4$ is *not* even then $n$ is *not* even." As you pointed out, this contrapositive is the same as saying "If $7n+4$ is odd then $n$ is odd"

Next, the backward direction is

> "If $7n+4$ is even then $n$ is even"

which is equivalent to the contrapositive statement "If $n$ is odd then $7n+4$ is odd."

So to complete your proof, you have to complete the proof in the forward direction (whether you do it directly or prove the contrapositive) *and* similarly you have to show the backward direction. Once you have done this, you may conclude that $n$ is even iff $7n+4$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement of the contrapositive is correct, except that the first "negative" should be "positive".

The argument you have given proves correctly that if $n$ is odd, then $7n+4$ is odd.

It remains to prove that if $7n+4$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.  Here is one possible proof.

Let $n$ be an integer and assume that $7n+4$ is odd.  Now $6n+4$ is obviously even, and the difference between an odd and an even number is odd, therefore $(7n+4)-(6n+4)$ is odd.  That is, $n$ is odd.  This completes the proof.

Comment: I'm not answering what was originally posted, but what I can see :)

Comment: Interesting. The OP kept editing his/her post while comments came in at the beginning so the flawed logic doesn't show up in the edit history now. :( What a mess.